# Using WordPress only for the backend, and using AngularJS as a frontend

Tags: htaccess, front-end, api

I'm developing a web application for a friend who needs an online portfolio. As a learning experience, I'm trying to do the front-end with AngularJS and using Wordpress as a backend with the official API plugin. It works really well, but there's a problem.

**I can't seem to completely hide the Wordpress frontend.** There might be something I'm missing, but I don't know how to set my website to exclusively use the Angular app for the frontend. Things I have tried:

- Modifying the `.htaccess` file to include `index.html` (the starting file of my Angular app) and `index.php` secondarily in order to keep being able to use the API calls from my app. This causes some problems: when I've navigated to, say, `mysite.com/page-one.html` and I reload the page, the WP site is loaded instead of my Angular app.
- Redirecting all pages (that are not within my app) to `index.html`.

These don't seem like robust solutions to me at all. I need to remove the Wordpress site and only use WP for the API. Am I missing something?

---

### Update

I have changed my focus on this question and have realized that I don't need to hide the WordPress front-end but rather actually use it. I'll answer the question, and maybe it'll inspire other, better answers by more knowledgeable people.

Comment: As it  is the question is too broad. How do you expect people to give you tips on improving you setup without giving any details about it?

Comment: You're right. I'll try to edit it in a minute to be more comprehensive. But I have had my own epiphany with it and will also post an answer soon. Maybe that answer will inspire another, better answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: I am posting an answer to my own question with hopes of it being useful for developers trying to solve the same problem that my initial query proposes.*

---

As it turns out, I was viewing this with the wrong lens. The solution was not to add my entire AngularJS app and use that while trying to disguise the WordPress front-end and themes. **The solution is actually to create a WordPress theme that uses my AngularJS app as a static starting page**, and build the app thereon.

I was inspired by this article: https://1fix.io/angularjs-wp-rest-api/

I can just build an AngularJS app and base it on the `index.php` file of a new theme. It was as easy as that. I guess I just couldn't see the forest for the trees.